# Flutter widget unittests throws No Directionality widget found

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, widget

i try to unittest a small own widget:

```
testWidgets('MyWidget has a title and message', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  var text = "abc";
  var label = "def";

  await tester.pumpWidget(LabeledTextWidget(
    text,
    label: label,
  ));

  final textFinder = find.text(text);
  final labelFinder = find.text(label);

  expect(textFinder , findsOneWidget);
  expect(labelFinder, findsOneWidget);
});
```

Here is the widget code:

```
class LabeledTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String label;
  LabeledTextWidget(this.text, {this.label});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
         Text(label,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,),
         Text(text),
         ],
    );
  }
```

The test always throws the exception:

```
...
No Directionality widget found.
RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Directionality ancestor was:
RichText
...
```

I can avoid this error by adding a text direction to all Text-Widgets. (textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,), but i thats a bad solution and it doesn´t work with rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution.

You have to wrap the Widget with this:

```
Directionality(
  child: MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData(),
    child: LabeledTextWidget(this.text, {this.label}),
  ),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

In a real world Flutter app be preapred that the Widget under test might depend on a whole bunch of framework widgets that should preceed it and you can face numerous errors:

*No Directionality widget found, No MaterialLocalizations found, No material widget, No Overlay, etc.*

The best way to go is to digest the `main.dart` entry point and extract the bare minimum (via trial and error). Here's my `pumpWidget` example were I create and wrap the target `OnlineDictionaries` widget:

```
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<OnlineDictionaryManager>(
          create: (context) => OnlineDictionaryManager(FakeOnlineRepo()),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''),
          const Locale('be', ''),
          const Locale('ru', ''),
        ],
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {'/': (context) => Scaffold(body: OnlineDictionaries())},
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Note that the `OnlineDictionaries` widget relies on Providers for state management, it uses localizations and the app uses Overlays/Navigator (addressed by `initialRoute` and `routes` properties).

Afterwards you can manipulate the widget (e.g. checking if load indicator is displayed and if an error message is shown if TextFormField is cleared):

```
  await tester
      .pump(Duration(milliseconds: 10)); // let progress indicator appear

  expect(find.byType(LinearProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  var field = find.byType(TextFormField);

  expect(field, findsOneWidget);

  await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextFormField), '');

  await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

  final errorFinder = find.text('URL can\'t be empty');

  expect(errorFinder, findsOneWidget);
```

Here's a complete example (also includes Mockito and mocking SharedPreferences): https://github.com/maxim-saplin/dikt/blob/master/test/ui_dictionaries_test.dart